# How to convert a string of values with a range to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, range

I'm trying to parse a string of numbers and ranges joined by `","`, and convert it to a numerical array. I have this as input: `"1,3,6-8,5"`, and would like to have an array like this: `[1,3,5,6,7,8]`.

I can only do it without the range, like this:

```
"12,2,6".split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }.sort #=> [2, 6, 12]
```

With a range, I cannot do it:

```
a = "12,3-5,2,6"
b = a.gsub(/-/, "..")               #=> "12,3..5,2,6"
c = b.split(",")                    #=> ["12", "3..5", "2", "6"]
d = c.sort_by(&:to_i)               #=> ["2", "3..5", "6", "12"]
e = d.split(",").map { |s| s.to_i } #>> Error
```

How can I do this?

I was also thinking to use the splat operator in `map`, but splat doesn't accept strings like `[*(3..5)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"12,3-5,2,6".
  gsub(/(\d+)-(\d+)/) { ($1..$2).to_a.join(',') }.
  split(',').
  map(&:to_i)
#⇒ [12, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6]
```

Comment: For the benefit of the wider community it is usual to add some explanation to code only answers, otherwise they end up in the LQP queue for review like this one did....

Comment: Definitely the most easy answer to wrap my head around. No maps, and no if/then loops. Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

```
"1,3,6-8,5".split(',').map do |str|
  if matched = str.match(/(\d+)\-(\d+)/)
    (matched[1].to_i..matched[2].to_i).to_a
  else
    str.to_i
  end
end.flatten
```

or

```
"1,3,6-8,5".split(',').each_with_object([]) do |str, output|
  if matched = str.match(/(\d+)\-(\d+)/)
    output.concat (matched[1].to_i..matched[2].to_i).to_a
  else
    output << str.to_i
  end
end
```

or strict

```
RANGE_PATTERN = /\A(\d+)\-(\d+)\z/
INT_PATTERN   = /\A\d+\z/

"1,3,6-8,5".split(',').each_with_object([]) do |str, output|
  if matched = str.match(RANGE_PATTERN)
    output.concat (matched[1].to_i..matched[2].to_i).to_a

  elsif str.match(INT_PATTERN)
    output << str.to_i

  else
    raise 'Wrong format given'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"1,3,6-8,5".split(',').flat_map do |s|
  if s.include?('-')
    f,l = s.split('-').map(&:to_i)
    (f..l).to_a
  else
    s.to_i
  end
end.sort
  #=> [1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"1,3,6-8,5"
.scan(/(\d+)\-(\d+)|(\d+)/)
.flat_map{|low, high, num| num&.to_i || (low.to_i..high.to_i).to_a}
#=> [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 5]
```